# List associated Gerrit patch set number for local branch downloaded via git-review

Tags: git, gerrit, git-review

#### Gerrit patch set number associated with local branch downloaded using git-review

Consider a change in Gerrit, say change `1234`, having the following patch sets

```
# Gerrit change 1234 (https://mygerrit.somewhere.net/#/c/1234/)
1 (original commit)
2 (some amendments)
3 (some amendments)
```

And that I checkout patch set `2` of the change using [`git-review`](https://docs.openstack.org/infra/git-review/usage.html):

```
$ git review -d 1234,2
Downloading refs/changes/00/1234/2 from gerrit
Switched to branch "review/foo_bar/1234"
```

**Question:**

- While on branch `review/foo_bar/1234` (no changes after the `review` command above), is it somewhat possible to query the Gerrit patch set number associated with the branch? I.e.

  ```
  $ ... ?
  2
  ```

The only approach I've come up with myself is to make use of `git ls-remote` to identify all patch set numbers (and their associated SHA hashes) for the given change, and thereafter compare the hashes against the hash of the local branch's `HEAD` (`git rev-parse HEAD`). Alternatively just matching the hash of local `HEAD` to the `git ls-remote` and extract the patch set number from there, but I was hoping for a neater approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query gerrit using the ssh query interface and the commit id.  For example, if my gerrit remote is...

```
$ git remote -v
gerrit  ssh://lars@review.openstack.org:29418/openstack/tripleo-quickstart.git (fetch)
```

...then I can make a gerrit query like this:

```
ssh -p 29418 lars@review.openstack.org gerrit query $(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

Just for kicks I grabbed patchset `415754`, which gets me:

```
$ git log -1
commit c5852f3f29f0a08236261772e8cd892eba381597 (HEAD -> review/leif_madsen/415754)
```

If I run the above `ssh ...` query, I'll get back a chunk of text that will include something like:

```
  patchSets:
    number: 1
    revision: a8eedf9e6c87f6542ea1802a493d9d5caa7acaa2
    [...]
  patchSets:
    number: 2
    revision: c5852f3f29f0a08236261772e8cd892eba381597
    [...]
```

Just look for the patch set that matches your current commit ID.  In this case, you can see that I have patchset 2.

You can automate that by (a) asking for JSON output with `--format json` and (b) using a JSON query tool such as `jq`:

```
$ ssh -p 29418 lars@review.openstack.org gerrit query \
  $(git rev-parse HEAD) --patch-sets --format json |
  head -1 | jq '.patchSets[] |
  select(.revision=="'"$(git rev-parse HEAD)"'").ref'
```

Which produces, in this case, the output:

```
"refs/changes/54/415754/2"
```

Comment: Thanks! I deliberately constrained my question to not include the trickier case (I myself have no idea how to approach this) where the local `HEAD` has been modified (amended): do you have any thoughts on how to possibly approach the case where the hash of `HEAD` is no longer matching any PS hash (handle: find out which PS `HEAD` was based upon)? Say for a use case with a commit hook that warns a user if the PS the local branch’s `HEAD` was based upon does not match the most current one on gerrit.

Comment: That's easy. In that case, your gerrit query would return 0 results; the JSON repsonse would look something like `{"type":"stats","rowCount":0,"runTimeMilliseconds":4,"moreChanges":false}`. You could easily check for that in a script.

Comment: I was possibly a bit unclear in my last comment, sorry for that: the tricky part in this “hard scenario” is not how to analyze whether a PS (`HEAD`) is already present or not on gerrit, but how to (as I wrote, I don’t even have an idea myself; some local dict. caching of which PS was most recently downloaded for a given change?) see whether a given new yet-to-be-pushed PS were based on the most recent gerrit PS or not. In my example, basing a new PS(/amendment) on `2` would yield a warning/prompt from the hook, whereas a new PS based on `3` would not.